# how to POST Json object to a webservice

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to consume a webservice and post the JSON object as request in my program. JSON is nested.

```
{
    "paymentorder": {
        "operation": "Purchase",
        "currency": "NOK",
        "amount": 15610,
        "vatAmount": 3122,
        "description": "Test Purchase",
        "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0...",
        "language": "nb-NO",
        "urls": {
            "hostUrls": ["https://localhost:9002", "https://powertools.local:9002"],
            "completeUrl": "https://powertools.local:9002/payment-completed",
            "cancelUrl": "https://powertools.local:9002/payment-canceled",
            "callbackUrl": "https://powertools.local:9002/payment-callback",
            "termsOfServiceUrl": "https://powertools.local:9002/termsandconditoons.pdf"
        },
        "payeeInfo": {  
            "payeeId": "20f3341c-e570-40a1-b76f-5347f4866de8",
            "payeeReference": "P4555334",
            "payeeName": "Kiran Vemula",
            "productCategory": "P00432101",
            "orderReference" : "P45553234"
        },
        "payer": {
            "consumerProfileRef": "63adb0760ebdcca15d8475773a59c3f3b03df6222dfcc9f5740ce1eb3465f58e"
        }
    }
}
```

the build the Hashmaps like below:

```
    private Map<String, Object> initiatePaymentMenuRequestBody(){
        final Map<String, Object> paymentorderChilds = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
        paymentorderChilds.put("operation", "Purchase");
        paymentorderChilds.put("currency",currency);
        paymentorderChilds.put("amount",amount);
        paymentorderChilds.put("vatAmount",vatAmount);
        paymentorderChilds.put("description",description);
        paymentorderChilds.put("userAgent",userAgent);
        paymentorderChilds.put("language",language);
        paymentorderChilds.put("urls", initiatePaymentMenuURLs());
        paymentorderChilds.put("payeeInfo", initiatePaymentMenuPayeeInfo());
        paymentorderChilds.put("payer", initiatePaymentMenuPayer());
        return paymentorderChilds;
    }

    private Map initiatePaymentMenuURLs(){
        final Map<String, Object> initiatePaymentMenuURLs = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
        List<String> hostUrls = new ArrayList<>();
        hostUrls.add(mediqHostUrls1);
        hostUrls.add(mediqHostUrls2);
        initiatePaymentMenuURLs.put("hostUrls",hostUrls);
        initiatePaymentMenuURLs.put("completeUrl",completeUrl);
        initiatePaymentMenuURLs.put("cancelUrl",cancelUrl);
        initiatePaymentMenuURLs.put("callbackUrl",callbackUrl);
        initiatePaymentMenuURLs.put("termsOfServiceUrl",termsOfServiceUrl);

        return initiatePaymentMenuURLs;
    }

    // implement this method with the real data from B2CCustomer and Cart object
    private Map initiatePaymentMenuPayeeInfo(){
        Map<String, String> initiatePaymentMenuPayeeInfo = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        initiatePaymentMenuPayeeInfo.put("payeeId",metchantID);
        initiatePaymentMenuPayeeInfo.put("payeeReference",payeeReference);
        initiatePaymentMenuPayeeInfo.put("payeeName",payeeName);
        initiatePaymentMenuPayeeInfo.put("productCategory",productCategory);
        initiatePaymentMenuPayeeInfo.put("orderReference",orderReference);
        return initiatePaymentMenuPayeeInfo;
    }

    private Map initiatePaymentMenuPayer(){
        Map<String, String> initiatePaymentMenuPayer = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        initiatePaymentMenuPayer.put("consumerProfileRef", initiateConsumerSession());
        return initiatePaymentMenuPayer;
    }
```

and finally calling the webservice to post the data:

```
    @Override
    public String initiatePaymentMenu(PaymentOrder paymentOrder1) {
        final RestTemplate restTemplate2 = new RestTemplate();
        final UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(host+initiatePaymentMenuhostpostfix);
        Map paymentOrder = new HashMap();
        paymentOrder.put("paymentorder", initiatePaymentMenuRequestBody());
        final HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(paymentOrder,getHeadders());
        LOG.info("initiatePaymentMenu===========> "+entity.getBody());
        ResponseEntity<String> payExInitiatePaymentMenuResponse = restTemplate2.postForEntity(builder.build().encode().toUri(),entity,String.class);
        LOG.info("initiatePaymentMenu" +payExInitiatePaymentMenuResponse.getStatusCode());
        String returnString = payExInitiatePaymentMenuResponse.getStatusCode().toString();
        return returnString;
    }
```

Is I am doing the correct way? I am not getting the response and giving me 400 error. Is entity.getBody() prints the exact JSON? can I use it in postman to check the response?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should use postman(or any other application or browser extension in this type) instead of your application for sending request to that web server. After you get correct response in postman, then switch back to your application and test it. Also, you said the server giving 404 error, it means bad request. Probably complete error title and body can help you fixing problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used the postman, I am getting a proper response. is there any way to check the json of my reqest. I was trying to print entity.getBody() on console, but, its not exact the same JSON that is expected as described above. below is the console out put.```{
 paymentorder={
  operation=Purchase, 
  currency=NOK, 
  amount=1235, 
  vatAmount=3122, 
  description=Test Purchase, 
  userAgent=Mozilla 5.0.., 
  language=nb-NO, 
  urls={
   hostUrls=[https://electronics.local:9002, https://training.local:9002], 
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.  The web service is not accepting 2 different URLs in hostUrls field. It was a bug in the web service provider itself.